# Не вижу содержимое массива в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Содержимое проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое файлов:

**\blog\views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
from .models import Branchs

def branch_list(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {})
```

**\blog\models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from io import BytesIO
import subprocess

class Branchs(models.Model):
    result = subprocess.run("gitlab project-branch list --project-id 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8').stdout
    br_list = result.replace('\n\n','\n').replace('\n\n','\n').replace('name: ','').replace(', ','\n')
    split_list = br_list.split('\n')
    parsed_branches = split_list[:-1] 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.parsed_branches
```

**\blog\branch_list.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import models

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.branch_list, name='branch_list'),
]
```

**\blog\templates\blog\branch_list.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Code loading to GitLab</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>branch</p>
        <div class="branch">
           <select>
              {% for branchs in parsed_branches %} 
        <option>{{ branchs }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
       </select>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**\blog\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.branch_list, name='branch_list'),
]
```

В итоге списка бранчей на странице не вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как полечить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете модели не по назначению. Модели в django предназначены для работой с БД. И так же как сказано в предыдущем ответе вам нужно передать ваши данные в шаблон. Вам нужно сделать следующее:

**\blog\views.py**

```
import subprocess
from django.shortcuts import render


def branch_list(request):
    result = subprocess.run("gitlab project-branch list --project-id 3", 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8').stdout
    br_list = result.replace('\n\n','\n').replace('\n\n','\n').replace('name:','').replace(', ','\n')
    split_list = br_list.split('\n')
    parsed_branches = split_list[:-1] 
    return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {'parsed_branches': parsed_branches })
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Ну так ты же во вьюшке в `def branch_list(request)` ничего не передаешь из бд.

```
def branch_list(request):
    branches = Branchs.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/branch_list.html', {'branches':branches})
```

и в шаблоне

```
<select>
    {% for a in branches %} 
    <option>{{ a.parsed_branches }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Мне ничего из БД и не нужно передавать. Я оборачиваю результат команды ОС в массив как class и хочу его передавать форме при открытии